# OLS multiple regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients

I am running multiple variable OLS regressions in stata and a bit confused about something. In my understanding, OLS coefficients are computed so that the sum of $(observed - predicted data points)^2 $be minimized?

If this is indeed the case, how can the inclusion of a additional variable lead to the $(observed - predicted)^2$ equal a higher number? Shouldn't the new variable be given a coefficient of 0 if it can't reduce the $(observed - predicted)^2$?

Comment: You're right, it cannot increase that value on the data the model is trained on.  It very much can increase that value on hold out data, which is the basis of model testing.

Comment: If by predicted you mean the fitted value then Matthew's point is correct and important.

Comment: It is sometimes helpful in problems of this sort to verify that the two analyses are using the same observations.

Comment: Your question seems to rely on a false premise. Can you give more details so we can help untangle what caused you to think this?

Answer (score 0):

Numerical funkiness can cause this when you do the math on a computer, but that is a limitation of the computer. You are correct about the math...

...on the development data.

When you go do test new points, you might find that including a predictor causes the out-of-sample performance to decrease.